# jQuery plugins for blog posts

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xhtml

I can use a page or multiple pages to display user's info with their most recent post. Any ideas on how to approach this? Are there any jQuery plugins available for this?

This was a question asked in an interview. I thought of using login screen, so that I'll know the user and get his info from the cookie. But I've been also asked to use jQuery plugin in someway..But I didn't know how to approach it.. Suggestions please

Comment: @typeof - this is not a realtime blog page. I'm thinking of having 2 pages for 2 users and what ever the user who logged in types get displayed. Old content shouldn't be there. Will this approach work??

Comment: Any website that has a login page has some sort of authentication layer on the server-side -- which usually involves a database. You'll also need a database for keeping the content the users create.  This is all independent of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogging software lives server-side, so anything that you do client-side (jQuery) would have to depend on the blog software's AJAX capability.